# take the data in the table with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to retrieve the data in the table and then make it into a chart

please help how to retrieve the data in the total id as a whole

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9irUg.jpg)

[image]

```html
</table>
  <label for="">Table Hasil</label>
  <table class="table" border="1" id="hasil">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Alternatif</th>
        <th>C1</th>
        <th>C2</th>
        <th>C3</th>
        <th>C4</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php $i=1; foreach ($saw as $s) { ?>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <?= $i++ ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $s->alternatif ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $a = round($s->c1/$nilaiMax->c1 *0.25,2) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $b = round($s->c2/$nilaiMax->c2 *0.25,2 ) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $c = round($s->c3/$nilaiMax->c3*0.3,2) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $d = round($s->c4/$nilaiMax->c4*0.2,2) ?>
        </td>
        <td id="total">
          <?= $total = $a+$b+$c+$d ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

thank you for the help

Comment: What have you tried so far to make that data appear as a chart?

Comment: what is your expected? an javascript object with id and total property?

Comment: Remove tabs from code samples and replace with spaces; deep indentation makes code harder to read in the code block panel.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Your code has some syntax errors. Maybe, try to write everything in a string (`$html`), so that you could debug it easier.

I'm not sure what `$saw` and `$s` variables are. If you could `print();` and add it to your question, it would have been much easier.

```
$html = '
            <label for="">Table Hasil</label>
            <table class="table" border="1" id="hasil">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Alternatif</th>
                    <th>C1</th>
                    <th>C2</th>
                    <th>C3</th>
                    <th>C4</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
';

$i = 1;

foreach ($saw as $s) {
    $html .= '<tr><td>' . $i++ . '</td><td>';
    $html .= $s->alternatif . '</td><td>';
    $html .= round($s->c1 / $nilaiMax->c1 * 0.25, 2) . '</td><td>';
    $html .= round($s->c2 / $nilaiMax->c2 * 0.25, 2) . '</td><td>';
    $html .= round($s->c3 / $nilaiMax->c3 * 0.3, 2) . '</td><td>';
    $html .= round($s->c4 / $nilaiMax->c4 * 0.2, 2) . '</td><td>';
    $html .= '<td id="total">' . $a + $b + $c + $d . '</td><td>';
}

$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of id

```
<td id="total">
    <?= $total = $a+$b+$c+$d ?>
</td>
```

Make it into a class

```
<td class="total">
    <?= $total = $a+$b+$c+$d ?>
</td>
```

And if you have Jquery installed, you can try this, this will retrieve the total of all the value in the total column

```
var totalVal;
$('.total').each( function(index, element) {
    totalVal += parseInt(element.html());
});
```